# How to get an updated version of the function in class when changing input?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have this fitness function in this class, I have changed the attributes of an instance of this class, however when calling the function I want the returned value to be updated with the modified input, how can I achieve this? (I wanted to get the output of 12)

```
class ready:
 def __init__(self,x):
    self.x=x
    self.fitness=fit(self.x)
    
def fit(z):
    return z
p=ready(10)   
p.x=12
print(p.fitness)
```

Comment: Seems like you want `ready.fitness` to be a function (or possibly a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)) instead of a member variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it: to make `self.fitness` update according to `self.x`, you can make fitness a class property instead of a variable, so each time you call it, it will return the harmonized value.

```
class ready:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
        
    @property
    def fitness(self):
        return fit(self.x)
        
def fit(z):
    return z
p=ready(10)   
p.x=12
print(p.fitness)
```

Output:

> 12

Answer (score -2):

You already updated your x value, but you dont print it. You are printing p.fitness.
When you print p.x you will see you changed the value of x.
Or you just change the value of p.fitness.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).